# Engine com menor consumo de RAM que InnoDB/XtraDB no MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, innodb

O InnoDB permite fazer vários `INSERT` e também `UPDATE` sem criar `LOCKING`, enquanto no MyISAM não é possível fazer vários INSERT ao mesmo tempo e para piorar a situação o MyISAM não suporta `TRANSACTION`.

Porém, o InnoDB parece armazenar todos os dados em RAM enquanto o MyISAM armazena apenas os indexes, o que é uma baita economia de memória RAM.

**O meu problema:**

Muitas tabelas são registros como se fosse um "Log", isso é cada transação que o usuário faz fica registrado e isso logicamente não pode ser apagado em nenhum momento, entretanto é raras as situações onde existe algum `SELECT`, existem tabelas onde 90% do tempo é somente escrita.

Por esse motivo o InnoDB é usado, porque existem muitas e muitas escritas e rollbacks. Porém o sistema de uso de RAM do InnoDB exige muita RAM, sendo que neste caso não seria necessário, porque existe pouco SELECT. Acredito que o uso de RAM é necessário quando existem muito SELECT, dessa forma os indexes e o conteúdo já estaria disponível na hora. Mas, nesse caso é desperdício.

Enquanto isso existem tabelas que existem muitas escritas e leituras, que são afetados pela falta de memoria.

*PS: O servidor tem 64GB de RAM e é exclusivo para o MariaDB*

**Existe alguma engine alternativa ao InnoDB/XtraDB para o MariaDB 10.1?**

Comment: Você configura do jeito que você quer. Se quer que ocupe pouca memória para cada coisa, basta configurar.

Comment: Como posso limitar o consumo de apenas uma tabela para priorizar outra tabela? Exemplo, duas tabelas "A" com 20GB (com muito mais leitura) e "B" com 30GB (somente escrita). Se o limite do innodb_buffer_pool_size for de 40GB, como posso fazer para que apenas a tabela "A" utilize tais 40GB?

Comment: Isso já é outra pergunta totalmente diferente dessa, que nem sei se pode ser respondida.